# How to update temporal document in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have requirement to change the position of the few fields in my historical harmonized data(temporal).Which function I can use for this

Comment: you might want to elaborate your question with details and also what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporal functions, but generally you cannot do *any* non-temporal operations on a temporal document, if that is what you are asking.  You can use

https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal:collection-set-options

to allow an override.  With the override you can do *any* non-temporal operation.

The issue is that temporal queries are not guaranteed consistent in the presence of non-temporal updates.  The results of a temporal query can be different after an override update is made.